# Avoid manual column creation in Teradata SQL

Tags: powerbi, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Consider the following Teradata View named 'VIEW' which consists of Transactional data.

```
ATTR1 ATTR2  DATE1       DATE2      WEEK1   WEEK2 AMOUNT

A       B   1/1/2019    1/8/2019    201901  201902  10
A       B   12/26/2018  1/8/2019    201852  201902  20
A       B   1/1/2019    1/15/2019   201901  201903  30
A       B   1/8/2019    1/15/2019   201902  201903  30
```

DATE1 is a Posting Date and DATE2 is the clearing date of the transaction. WEEK1 and WEEK2 are the fiscal weeks of DATE1 and DATE2 respectively. ATTR are random attributes of the transaction. I need to report the transaction amounts by the 'week of' for the attributes.

For example for Week 201901 we would like to see the transactions amounts of posting dates of and before Week 201901 and the clearing dates after 201901. See code below.

```
select ATTR1,
       ATTR2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK2 > 201852 AND WEEK1 <= 201852 THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMT_201852,
       SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK2 > 201901 AND WEEK1 <= 201901 THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMT_201901,
       SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK2 > 201902 AND WEEK1 <= 201902 THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMT_201902,
FROM VIEW
GROUP BY 1,2
```

The result:

```
ATTR1   ATTR2   AMT_201852  AMT_201901  AMT_201902
A        B          20          60          60
```

As the code above suggests, we are having to manually create columns for each week which we would like to avoid. Is there a way to dynamically create these columns as the weeks pass by? Or is there a better way to represent this?
In a report, using WEEK1 as a filter will filter out the earlier weeks (In case of WEEK1 as 201901, 201852 will be filtered out and lose the respective amounts). We eventually put this SQL into a PowerBI dashboard.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you always report the same number of weeks or is it variable? How are your weeks defined, ISO?

Comment: @dnoeth The weeks will change as our reports are in a rolling based format. We keep about 30 weeks of history. Yes I believe the weeks are defined as per ISO.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to mess around with this a bit, but it should get you going in the right direction.
Teradata has an extremely useful date view built in:  `sys_calendar.calendar`

This, for example, will get you the past three weeks in the format you have them in your sample data (YYYYWW):

```
select
    distinct week_of_year,
    year_of_calendar,
    (year_of_calendar * 100) + week_of_year as year_week
from
sys_calendar.calendar
where
calendar_date between  (current_date - interval '21' day) and current_date
order by year_week
```

You should be able to replace current_date with a parameter to make this dynamic, and join this to your table.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your response. However, I am not sure how this helps as I already have a fiscal calendar table where I am looking up the WEEK1 and WEEK2 from. The table contains both historical and future weeks.

Comment: Well, depending on what your fiscal table looks like, you could probably do something similar with it.

Comment: I am not able to understand your solution here. Could you explain this in a little bit more detail? I have edited my question in case I wasn't clear.

Comment: Hi All, any ideas? I haven't been able to figure out a way forward yet.